# (Un-)Countable union of open sets

Tags: general-topology

Let $A_i$ be open subsets of $\Omega$. Then $A_0 \cap A_1$ and $A_0 \cup A_1$ are open sets as well.

Thereby follows, that also $\bigcap_{i=1}^N A_i$ and $\bigcup_{i=1}^N A_i$ are open sets.

My question is, does thereby follow that $\bigcap_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i$ and $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_i$ are open sets as well?

And what about $\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i$ and $\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$ for uncountabe $I$?

Comment: Ok, it is an axiom for a topologies. But then there should be a proof for metrik spaces, say $\mathbb{R}$ with the canonical metrik? So to say, that every point $x \in \bigcap_{i \in I} A_i$ is an inner point.

Comment: A remark: regardless of whether it is true that an infinite union or intersection of open sets is open, when you have a property that holds for every finite collection of sets (in this case, the union or intersection of any _finite collection_ of open sets is open) the validity of the property for an infinite collection doesn't follow _from that_. In other words, induction helps you prove a proposition for any natural number, but not for any transfinite cardinal. You'll have to use different techniques to prove or disprove the statement in your questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The union of **any** collection of open sets is open. Let $x \in \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$, with $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ a collection of open sets. Then, $x$ is an interior point of some $A_k$ and there is an open ball with center $x$ contained in $A_k$, therefore contained in $\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$, so this union is open. Others have given a counterexample for the infinite intersection of open sets, which isn't necessarily open.
By de Morgan's laws, the intersection of **any** collection of closed sets is closed (try to prove this), but consider the union of $\{x\}_{x\in (0,1)}$, which is $(0,1)$, not closed. The union of an infinite collection of closed sets isn't necessarily closed.

Comment: Thnk for your answer moreh

Answer (score 7):

Any union of a set of open sets is again open. However, infinite intersections of open sets need not be open. For example, the intersection of intervals $(-1/n,1/n)$ on the real line (for positive integers $n$) is precisely the singleton $\{0\}$, which is not open.

Comment: Is there a formal proof (without using counter example) why  infinite intersections of open sets need not be open?

Comment: When proving that something is not always true (such as "a countable intersection of open sets is open"), a counterexample **is** a formal proof. Generality is neither needed nor particularly helpful. We only need generality when proving universal statements.

Answer (score 7):

An arbitrary union (coutable or not) of open sets is open, but even for a countable intersection it's not true in general. For example, when $\Omega$ is the real line endowed with the usual topology, and $A_i:=\left(-\frac 1i,\frac 1i\right)$, $A_i$ is open but $\bigcap_{i\in \Bbb N}A_i=\{0\}$ which is not open.

Comment: Moreover (exercise for the reader), **any subset** of the ambient space (e.g. the reals) can be written as the intersection of some collection of open sets.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro: can you give some hints how to prove this?

Comment: Actually, Dave's assertion fails for the indiscrete topology...

Comment: @Thomas E.: Assume singleton sets are closed sets (to take care of GEdgar's observation). Then, given any subset $E,$ we can write $E$ as the union of a collection of singleton sets (use the points belonging to $E$), and hence $E$ can be written as the union of a collection of closed sets. By applying De Morgan's Law, we can now write the complement of $E$ as the intersection of a collection of open sets (the open sets will be co-singleton sets). Finally, note that as $E$ varies over all subsets of the ambient space, the complement of $E$ will vary over all subsets of the ambient space.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro. True, I didn't somehow even think about that :-) So $T_{1}$ would be the least requirement for this construction.