# Let $a$ and $b$ be arbitrary real numbers with $a < b$. Show that $[a,b]$ is closed by proving its complement is open.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $a$ and $b$ be arbitrary real numbers with $a < b$. Show that $[a,b]$ is closed by proving its complement is open.

I don't have any idea on this, can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Write down what it means for a set to be open. Show that $[a,b]^C$ satisfies this condition.

Comment: Yes, anymore than that hint would be akin to giving the solution outright. It may be safe to add: write out the complement as a union of certain sets, then note that they are both open, and conclude the union is open (why?). Best of luck!

Comment: Hi @Moses please explain in detail. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the definition of openness that was given in your previous question. Note that the complement of $[a,b]$ is $]\infty,a[ \cup ]b,\infty[$. For any point in this set, you can find a small open ball that is contained within the set.

Answer (score 2):

The answer was essentially given on comments. Here are some references.

[Any open interval is an open set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/906103/an-open-interval-is-an-open-set). Also, [the union of open sets is open](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/153929/70305).

The complement of $[a,b]$ is $(-\infty,a)\cup(b,\infty)$. So, it's open (union of open sets).